# Why is there a cutoff in population density running through the middle of the US?

Tags: united-states, demography, population

[image]

There is this interesting line cutting across the US in terms of population density. It cuts through Texas, Oklahoma, Kansas, and Nebraska. East is higher population density excluding some small pockets like northern Maine and west is lower excluding cities. I think that is where the explorers stopped. For a familiar manifestation of this, you can see this in the electoral votes of each state along this line. Oklahoma has seven, Kansas has six, and Nebraska has five. Each state I named has less of that yellow area.

What caused this bifurcation down a fuzzy line positioned in the same longitude as and north of the bottom of Texas?

Comment: Your question has been asked [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/58446/16951) (and closed ) before

Comment: @justCal - Huh. I'd say you're right. Is there something we could do to get that question reopened? The existence of this second question on the same topic pretty conclusively shows its a question we're liable to keep getting. It would be nice to have a good version of the question with good answers available.

Comment: Trying to accomplish anything during the tag edit storm is pointless...

Comment: @justCal - I think we may have that ironed out now. /hopelessoptimisim>

Comment: Lack of water, basically, plus mountains.  Look at your population map beside a map of average annual precipitation: https://www.eldoradoweather.com/climate/US%20Climate%20Maps/Lower%2048%20States/Precipitation/Mean%20Total%20Precipitation/Gallery/mean-total-precipitation.html  (Note the population clusters in the SF Bay Area and Southern California have aqueducts shipping water from the Sierra Nevada and elsewhere.)

Comment: Well, living in one of the cities on that line, I might also point out that we are at roughly the last navigable point on our tributary of the Mississippi (in our case, the Arkansas river). It would be a lot of research to check the others, but that may have something to do with it as well.